# select list from database is giving null

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I want to select a list from database but it retreives null

dao method:

```
public static List<Matiere> getAll() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
            Matiere M = null;
            Connection cnx = Connect.getConnection();
            String req = "select* from matiere";
            PreparedStatement st = cnx.prepareStatement(req);
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
            rs.next();
            System.out.println("cc " + M);

            return (List<Matiere>) M;

        }
```

loop jsp

```
<table border=1 width=80% align=center> 
<tr><th>ID</th><th>Libellé</th></tr>
<% 
List<Matiere>lg=AdminDAO.getAll();
for(Matiere m:lg){ %>
    <tr>
    <td>  <%=m.getId() %>   </td>
    <td><%=m.getLibelle() %> </td>
    </tr>
    <% } %>
 </table>
```

how to resolve that

Comment: Note that `select*` is not a valid SQL syntax .

Comment: which syntax is valid @Arnaud ?

Comment: You need a space between `select` and `*` .

Comment: where is the part in which you will be receiving values from db and storing into list.

Comment: even whith space the error persists! @Arnaud

Comment: @Nitika in jsp is already shown !

Comment: @jan i am asking in dao method. the question is: where you are adding values in list while doing rs.next()

Comment: I don't need servlet to pass through since I'm retreiving directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are not populating the result set to the `List`. In order to get the results from the `List`, you first need to populate it.

For example please check the below code,

```
public static List<Matiere> getAll()
{
    List<Matiere> matiere = new ArrayList<>();

    try
    {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM matiere";
        Connection con = Connect.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(SQL);
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(SQL);

        while(rs.next()) {
            Matiere m = new Matiere();

            //Here add your database fields
            m.setId(rs.getString("id"));
            m.setLibelle(rs.getString("libelle"));
            matiere.add(m);
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException e) {
        // Log any exceptions ...
    }
    finally() {
        // Always close your JDBC resources
        try {
            if (statement != null) {
                statement.close();
                statement=null;
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException e) {
            // Couldn't close statement
            }
    }
    return matiere;
}
```

Comment: This is what i was trying to say